# Dynamic Link in Fancy box jQuery for wordpress images

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dynamic, hyperlink, fancybox

I am designing a website in Wordpress.

I need help in Fancybox. I am using fancy box with elevate zoom. When we hover on the image, it gives a zoom in effect as in ecoomerce websites and when I click on it, a fancybox opens up with the bigger size image.

Now I want to add a link on this fancybox pop up window which will take the user to the dedicated page for that product. But I am not sure how to add a dynamic link in jQuery.

here is the snippet from fancybox jquery

```
        // HTML templates

        tpl: {
            wrap     : '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>',
            image    : '<img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" /><div class="fancybox-caption"><a href="**?page_id=**">Click here to view the details</a></div>',
            iframe   : '<iframe id="fancybox-frame{rnd}" name="fancybox-frame{rnd}" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen' + (IE ? ' allowtransparency="true"' : '') + '></iframe>',
            error    : '<p class="fancybox-error">The requested content cannot be loaded.<br/>Please try again later.</p>',
            closeBtn : '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>',
            next     : '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>',
            prev     : '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>'
        },
```

Thanks in Advance

Disha

Comment: rather than opening a IMAGE open a Iframe or DIV in which you have link and your image. Or simply look for title/caption and add your link there, I remeber I saw such caption demo in fancy box website itself.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Sumit. Let me try this, Will let you know if it worked.

Comment: I am sorry to say but I am really new to jquery and php development. My question was to provide dynamic link on the pop up with the image. As you said adding caption may help. But still how to give dynamic link from wordpres post??

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample I found in Fancybox example

http://jsfiddle.net/G5TC3/

Code that matter is BeforeShow: this example show Facebook link but you can easily replace it with your link or image or content.

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.title) {
            // New line
            this.title += '<br />';

            // Add tweet button
            this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

            // Add FaceBook like button
            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
        }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        // Render tweet button
        twttr.widgets.load();
    },
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }  
});
```

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ is url for fancybox home.

To added product link, put the URL as data-url in your a tag for fancy box and then change the beforeShow function to read that data-url from a tag I guess $(this).attr("data-url") should give that value. I didn't test it. but once you have url you can easily show it here.